# Trying to trace a function with if

Tags: haskell

```
expmod :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
expmod a n m | trace (show (a n m)) False = undefined
expmod a 0 m = 1
expmod a n m = let (q,r) = divMod n 2
               ans = expmod a q m
           if r == 0 then let ans = ans*ans `mod` m 
               in trace ("-->" ++ show ans) ans
           else let ans = ans*ans*a `mod` m
               in trace ("-->" ++ show ans) ans
```

I'm not sure why it's failing at the if statement

```
error: parse error on input `if'
   |
37 |                if (r == 0) then let ans = ans*ans `mod` m
   |                ^^
```

How do you trace a function that has if statements?

Comment: `if`, like everything else, is an expression, not a statement. You could write this more briefly as ``let ans' = ans * ans * (if r == 0 then 1 else a) `mod` m in trace ("-->" ++ show ans)``.

Comment: A "parse error" means that the compiler cannot make sense of the text of your program. Parsing is the first stage (more or less) in compilation, in which the compiler takes the text of your source code and builds data structures that can be used for subsequent stages of compilation (e.g. type checking).

Comment: @chepner I like the elegance of that one liner that's very convenient I didn't think of it like that!

Comment: `(show (a n m))` shows the result of calling function `a` with args `n` and `m`. You want something like `(show (a, n, m))` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The immediate issue

To answer your immediate question, you need an `in` to go with your `let` (the beginning of the third line in the code just below):

```
expmod a n m = let (q,r) = divMod n 2
                   ans   = expmod a q m
               in  if r == 0 then let ans = ans*ans `mod` m 
                                  in  trace ("-->" ++ show ans) ans
                             else let ans = ans*ans*a `mod` m
                                  in  trace ("-->" ++ show ans) ans
```

#### Additional tips

When you use `let ans =`, you're defining `ans`, so any `ans` on the right of the equal sign will refer to the `ans` on the left side of the equal sign, not any `ans` defined elsewhere. Thus, this will fail:

```
let ans = ans*ans `mod` m
```

It's just like saying `` let x = x*x `mod` m `` out of nowhere. It'll just give infinite recursion, so use a two different variable names for the two `ans`es.

---

Thirdly, an easier way is to use [`traceShowId :: Show a => a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId), which traces a value that has a `Show` instance. `traceShowId x` evaluates to `x`, so you can use it where you'd want to use `x`. It also traces `x`. For example:

```
expmod a n m = let (q,r) = divMod n 2
                   ans   = expmod a q m
               in  traceShowId $ if r == 0 then ans*ans   `mod` m 
                                           else ans*ans*a `mod` m
```

Much less typing that way. You can also use `trace "vvv" . traceShowId $` if the arrows were important.

Comment: Even shorter, you could just write ``traceShowId $ ans * ans * (if r == 0 then 1 else a) `mod` m``.